# SVN post-checkout and post-update message

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

Is there a way to configure an Apache Subversion server to display a message after every `svn checkout` and `svn update`?

Context: After migrating our code base from SVN to Git, we made most of our SVN server read-only using pre-commit hooks, which also display a message pointing to the new git home.

We don't want to completely disable the SVN server quite yet, read-only operations `svn co` and `svn up` should still be doable. Is a way to display a message pointing to the new git home to the users still using the SVN server. Some kind of post-checkout and post-update hooks, but I don't think these exist.

Comment: What SVN client do you use? Do you have control over your user's computers via Group Policy or some alternative?

Comment: @bahrep Sorry if I was not clear, I need to do this on the server side (on which I have admin rights). I do not have access to the user computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks always run on server side. Subversion does not provide server-side hooks that will show messages to users on client side after running read operations such as checkout or update. If you had control (you do not per your comment *I need to do this on the server side (on which I have admin rights). I do not have access to the user computer* over user computers you could install [client side hook scripts in TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks). But they will work with TortoiseSVN client only.

Comment: This is correct. Hooks on server side are available only for commit, locks and revision propert change. All of which are the write operations. No read operation commits are available from server side.

Comment: Is there any documentation about the lack of server-side hooks?

Comment: Yes in svn book it is mentioned. For server side hooks You can refer here http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.html . If using Visual SVN on windows you can also look there https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/